# vs code connect server failed on win10?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

The client is win10, and server is also win10.I had install ssh-server on win10 server side, and can use ssh command connect it.

The Client win10 had install vs-code,so I use vs-code `ssh-remote` extension connect my win10 server side.But the vs-code show errors,I found the win10 server side had successful download vs-code server,but it tell me can't connect it?

**Win10 Client Error**
[image]

**Win10 clinet vs-code log**

```
[17:42:56.318] Log Level: 2
[17:42:56.326] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a225443227d", attempt 1
[17:42:56.326] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[17:42:56.327] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[17:42:56.327] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:42:56.327] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[17:42:56.327] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[17:42:56.327] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[17:42:56.328] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[17:42:56.328] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[17:42:56.328] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[17:42:56.328] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[17:42:56.332] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:42:56.332] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[17:42:56.332] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[17:42:56.333] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[17:42:56.333] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[17:42:56.333] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[17:42:56.333] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[17:42:56.335] VS Code version: 1.84.2
[17:42:56.335] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.107.1
[17:42:56.335] win32 x64
[17:42:56.336] SSH Resolver called for host: TC
[17:42:56.336] Setting up SSH remote "TC"
[17:42:56.339] Using commit id "1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e" and quality "stable" for server
[17:42:56.341] Install and start server if needed
[17:42:58.429] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MvCodeCameraSDK\Runtime\Win64_x64\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.432] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MvCodeCameraSDK\Runtime\Win64_x64\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.432] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MvCodeCameraSDK\Runtime\Win32_i86\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.433] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MvCodeCameraSDK\Runtime\Win32_i86\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.433] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MVS\Runtime\Win32_i86\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.434] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MVS\Runtime\Win32_i86\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.434] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MVS\Runtime\Win64_x64\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.435] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MVS\Runtime\Win64_x64\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.435] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.436] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.436] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\libnvvp\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.437] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\libnvvp\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.437] Checking ssh with "C:\Python32\Scripts\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.438] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python32\Scripts\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.438] Checking ssh with "C:\Python32\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.439] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.439] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.440] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.440] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.441] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.441] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.441] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.441] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.442] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[17:42:58.442] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[17:42:58.462] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[17:42:58.465] Remote command length: 6226/8192 characters
[17:42:58.465] Running script with connection command: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 18518 "TC" powershell
[17:42:58.466] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[17:42:58.985] > Windows PowerShell
> ��Ȩ���� (C) Microsoft Corporation����������Ȩ����
> 
> �����µĿ�ƽ̨ PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[17:42:58.985] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:42:58.993] > 
[17:42:59.497] > PS C:\Users\admin> 
[17:42:59.743] > 
[17:42:59.751] > PS C:\Users\admin> $uuid="4350bf0c139e"
[17:42:59.760] > PS C:\Users\admin> 
[17:42:59.769] > "${uuid}: running"
[17:42:59.779] > 4350bf0c139e: running
> PS C:\Users\admin> "4350bf0c139e: pauseLog
[17:43:00.093] > 4350bf0c139e: resumeLog
> PS C:\Users\admin> main
[17:43:00.103] > 
[17:43:00.274] > Acquiring lock on C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec4
> 63cf99d7768e\vscode-remote-lock.1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e        
> Looking for existing server in C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0f
> bba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
[17:43:00.284] > 
> Downloading server ia32
> 4350bf0c139e%%1%%
[17:43:00.291] > 
[17:43:05.174] > Expanding server into C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2xt2cv2j.c41
> 4350bf0c139e%%2%%
[17:43:05.180] > 
[17:43:25.701] > 
> 
>     Ŀ¼: C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server
> 
> 
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
> 
> ----                -------------         ------ ----
> 
> -a----        2023/12/1     17:43              0 .1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463
> cf99d7768e.token
[17:43:25.710] > 
> �ѳɹ����� 1 ���ļ�; ���� 0 ���ļ�ʱʧ��
[17:43:25.716] > �ѳɹ����� 1 ���ļ�; ���� 0 ���ļ�ʱʧ��
[17:43:25.725] > �ѳɹ����� 1 ���ļ�; ���� 0 ���ļ�ʱʧ��
[17:43:25.731] > �ѳɹ����� 1 ���ļ�; ���� 0 ���ļ�ʱʧ��
> Starting server: & 'C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7e
> c463cf99d7768e\bin\code-server.cmd' --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-ser
> ver-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --connection-token-file
>  'C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\.1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e.token'
>  --telemetry-level all  *> 'C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\.1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f1
> 4db7ec463cf99d7768e.log'
[17:43:25.745] > 
[17:43:29.800] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at C:\Users\admin\.vscode-ser
> ver\.1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e.log >>>
> C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e\bin\c
> ode-server.cmd : �ð汾�� C:\Users\admin\.v
> scode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e\node.exe �������е� Win
> dows �汾�����ݡ���鿴�������ϵͳ��Ϣ��Ȼ����ϵ��������ߡ�
> ����λ�� ��:1 �ַ�: 1
> + C:\Users\admin\.vscode-server\bin\1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d ...     
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (�ð汾�� C:\Users\a...ϵͳ��Ϣ��Ȼ����ϵ��
> ������ߡ�:String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> 
> <<< End of server log
> 4350bf0c139e: start
[17:43:29.806] > 
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==windows==
> osVersion====
> arch==ia32==
> platform==windows==
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==False==
> downloadTime==4886==
> installTime==20503==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==85==
> 4350bf0c139e: end
[17:43:29.806] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==windows==
osVersion====
arch==ia32==
platform==windows==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==False==
downloadTime==4886==
installTime==20503==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==85==

[17:43:29.807] Resolver error: Error: VS Code 服务器启动失败
    at g.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:642637)
    at d (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:636024)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:638294)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:761983)
    at async c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:722522
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:725828)
    at async I (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:719493)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:723199)
    at async c:\Users\jekoi\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:907003
[17:43:29.811] ------




[17:43:29.929] > 4350bf0c139e: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==windows==
> osVersion==10.0.18363==
> arch==ia32==
> platform==windows==
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==False==
> downloadTime==4886==
> installTime==20503==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==85==
> connectionToken==aaa11111-1111-11a1-111a-a11aaa1111a1==
> 4350bf0c139e: end
> 436, watching 2268
[17:43:29.981] > gps : �Ҳ������̱�ʶ��Ϊ 7952 �Ľ��̡�
> ����λ�� ��:3 �ַ�: 7
> + if (!(gps -Id $v_)) {
> +       ~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (7952:Int32) [Get-Process], Proces
> sCommandException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
> ands.GetProcessCommand
> 
> server died, exit
[17:43:31.172] "install" terminal command done
[17:43:31.173] Install terminal quit with output: server died, exit
```

---

**win10 server**
[image]